# Injection safe call to IAxaptaRecord.ExecuteStmt()

Tags: axapta, x++

Is there an injection safe way to call via the axpata business connector

```
string salesId = someObject.Text;

IAxaptaRecord salesLine = ax.CreateRecord("SalesLine");
salesLine.ExecuteStmt("select * from %1 where %1.SalesId == '" + salesId + "'");
```

If someObject.Text is set to the following, i am then vulnerable to x++ code injection:

```
"SomeSalesOrder' || %1.SalesId == 'SomeOtherOrder"
```

Is there a way to parametrize the query, or would it be better to write all of the data access code directly in x++, and then call that from COM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to be sure you have covered all cases ...

Using ExecuteStmt is most likely the wrong approach. You should write your select or whatever in an Axapta method (with parameters) then call that method.

Comment: Given you don't use literals, the default behaviour for simple queries is to use placeholders (parametrized queries), which is considered safe. For complex queries (joins) the only way to be sure is to use the ForcePlaceholders hint in joins.

Answer (score -2):

you should do a replace on ' to \'
e.g.

```
string salesId = someObject.Text.Replace("'", "\\'");
```

Comment: I am looking for a parametrization method handled by the framework to handle all edge cases, not just the example I gave

Comment: You could create an extension method for IAxaptaRecord that is something like 'ExecuteParametizedStmt(string query, params object[])

this would accept the query in a format expected by string.Format and build it that way, after performing the required work on the variables (such as escaping)

Comment: The whole issue is handling escaping correctly. If the query was "select * from %1.Id == {0}" (where {0} should be an int), and then "42 || 1 == 1" is passed in, injection will still occur after I have escaped it with the method you gave.

I don't know all of the edge cases of x++ injection here, so i don't want to write my own escaping method. Because if I do, chances are I would miss something, and I would only find out about it after it is too late. This is for a public facing web app with lots of confidential information, so i need to be 100% that there is no risk of injection.

Comment: By default simple queries use placeholders, but if you want to be 100% sure you should use the ForcePlaceholders keyword for joined queries. This is the X++ way to write parametrized queries. You can also take a look at the "Microsoft Dynamics AX Server Configuration Utility" where you can configure the default behavior for complex queries.