# Axapta.ExecuteStmt - Is it safe?

Tags: c#, axapta, ax

I have some code, which uses the ExecuteStmt method on the Axapta Object when using the Business Connector, like so:

```
AxaptaRecord record = (AxaptaRecord)ax.CreateAxaptaRecord("SalesTable");
record.ExecuteStmt("select * from %1 where %1.SalesId == '" + id + "'");
while (record.Found)
{
     // do stuff
}
```

This works fine, but it's going to be on a public facing website, so is this a good way of accessing the data and is it secure from SQL Injection? Because I've read that this statement will use the "forcePlaceholders" keyword which will parameterise the query as it doesn't contain a join?

Comment: Also have a look on the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/876547/4509

Comment: Where does `id` come from? Is there _any_ possibility I could change it to `'; DROP TABLE Students; --` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say no. this still reaks of sql injection.

Comment: You're right, I've just tried a "friendly" SQL Injection by passing: S215*' || %1.SalesId LIKE '*S209 as the id and it returned all s215 and all s209 results