# How to get return value from IAxaptaRecord::Call()?

Tags: c#, axapta, x++, ax, business-connector

In Dymanics AX 4.0, I want to run some methods under the Application Object Tree (AOT) > Data Dictionary > Tables > *CustTable* > Methods. (Could be any table at all)

This is mainly to get some custom calculated values, and also in part to deal with SQL injection
[Axapta.ExecuteStmt - Is it safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788446/axapta-executestmt-is-it-safe)

I found [AxaptaRecord.Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.dynamics.businessconnectornet.axaptarecord.call%28v=ax.10%29.aspx) documentation here but it doesn't help alot. Not sure if it is the correct method too. Also, what are the method call differences in terms of function types? e.g. public, static, server, return value types etc.

Hoping for some advice. Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? The question in the title doesn't really match what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those functions are intended to solve different problems in .NET that can easilly be solved from X++:

- `Axapta.ExecuteStmt` is the way to send some SQL (on the X++ internal SQL syntax) to the database that can be a select, update_recordset, etc. Exactly the same functionallity and results that if you write SQL commands inside the X++ code.
- `AxaptaRecord.Call` is a class method. That way, with this function you can only run record methods coded in X++ inside a table (those that can be found inside the *Methods* node on the AOT, like the usual .find() method).

EDIT: There is a third interesting method:

- `Axapta.CallStaticClassMethod`  is the way to execute an static method saved on a class. As the method needs to be static, you don't pass an object to the function, but just the class name and method name, as it is executed on a new context.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things to consider

1. It looks like you're trying to call Axapta objects from .Net, so the easiest way is to use the Business Connectory (Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet)
2. Create a wrapper class with static methods that understand how to instantiate the buffers and do the calculations you want (static method means you don't have a record/buffer for that table instantiated)

It (could) look something like this

```
    Axapta ax = new Axapta();
    try
    {
        //Note this is getting UserId out of web.config for a web service
        ax.LogonAs(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["uid"], "contoso.com", null, null, null, null, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["config"]);

        string returnString = (string)ax.CallStaticClassMethod("WrapperClassName", "StaticMethodName", _parameterPassedToMethod);
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between Axapta.CallStaticClassMethod() and AxaptaRecord.Call()? Can I use the latter to call static methods?

Comment: No, you cannot. That is why there are two methods.

Comment: I've editted my answer with the difference (quite obvious by the way).